# render message in 2 lines in pug file expressjs

Tags: express, pug, render

I have a expressjs route where i render a product.pug file.

```
 res.render('product', {
  title: '',
  message: 'Hello.\n'
      + '\n there.',
});
```

and now want to  render these in a new line in  a .pug file.Like `hello` in one line and `there` will be in another line.But it always shows in a single line

This is what i have done so far in pug/jade file to show the message
in two lines

```
   if message
         .alert.alert-danger(role='alert' style='background-color:#f2dede')
                                                        
                   p(style='color: black')
                                                            
                       message=message
```

How i can show the message in 2 lines .Can i also pass css through the message in express like font-weight,color. Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new line character in HTML text is rendered as a space, provided it is not adjacent to another space-like character.

To achieve what you want, your Pug view file has to be aware that your data is as you specified it to be. If so, then try:

```
if message
  .alert.alert-danger
    p!=message.replace(/\n/g, "<br/>")
```

The above is dangerous if you are not in control of the `message` contents. To be safe, add more code:

```
if message
  - const lines = message.split("\n")
  .alert.alert-danger
    each line,i in lines
      if i>0
        br
      | #{line}
```

The last conditional statement is to prevent an extra `<br/>` if there is no `\n` in `message`.

Comment: it worked. is there any way i can also pass css  through res.render for each line.I actually want to control each line with different css.for example in first line font will be bold and in the second line it will be normal font

Comment: One goal of a view file is to decouple your styling from your code or data. Your server should just take care of the application logic, build the data, and pass it to the view file. The view file then takes care of layout and styling. Therefore any CSS stuff should all be in the Pug file and not from the server. Please start a new question if it is about something I have missed.